# Recovering an Hierarchical Deterministic wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery, mnemonic-seed, deterministic-wallets

Does the use of an HD wallet (with BIP 32 and BIP 39) guarantee the possibility of its recovery in an HD wallet of any manufacturer, whether it's software or hardware?

Or sometimes there are cases of incompatibility of HD wallets due to different principles of their creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure they use the same derivation path. If there are a lot of unused addresses generated you may need to increase the gap limit.